# A Linux command that will display all files in a directory that: begin with FSDES, are larger than 16kb, were added within the last week(7days)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat-enterprise-linux

Looking for a Linux(Red Hat: Version 7.9 Maipo) command that will display all files in a directory that:

1. Begin with FSDES
2. Are larger than 16kb
3. Were added within the last week(7days)

Thank you.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this goal? This community doesn’t really answer questions where people effectively don’t do any work but just write about what they want. People need to show some effort.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Well someone has to say you. `:-)` What you asked for is more complex you supposed (added is created, modified, moven in...? and file is generic, someone will consider symbolic or hard links too, directory themseves...?). Many complains arose from some _lack of effort_ in your question, sometime it is enough to see `man command` to have the help. But you need to know the command name to use `man`, sometimes is `help command`... BTW try to [edit] your post and add some specifications and failed attempts you did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command:

```
find /directory/path -ctime -7 -name 'FSDES*' -size +16000
```

Comment: -7 will give only the last 6 days. I would advise you to read the manual pages but I won't.

Comment: The question says “files … that … were added within the last week (7 days)”.  “Added” is commonly used to mean “created”.  `-ctime` does not check when a file was created.  … … … … Also, since the question says “files”, you might want to add `-type f`.

Answer (score 1):

"find" is the command you're looking for. See "man find".

Comment: This community doesn’t really answer questions where people effectively don’t do any work but just write about what they want. People need to show some effort. And in the case of this answer, telling someone to “See `man find`.” is even less of the way the community helps each other. Telling someone to read the man page is no better than asking someone to Google something.

Comment: Yes, I most certainly agree with you on your comment.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I find your comment insulting to the people writing manual pages.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille You're entitled to hold that opinion, but you still have to respect our rules.

Comment: @gronostaj as can be seen in the accepted answer.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille The accepted answer is the accepted answer because it provides a solution. Buy your “answer” provides no context past, “Go read the man page for `find`.” Someone who does not know what to look for will read that page and be baffled more than helped. Thus this answer as you posted it is just unhelpful at best.